# if isset breaking my php

Tags: php, html, if-statement, echo

I'm trying to build a SQL statement using variables that were posted on a previous page (show the SQL statement for copy-pasting in a div using echo), however, the one statement is preventing me from doing it.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['locationName'])) {
        echo $_POST['locationName'];
    }
?>
```

As soon as I've put that in, the page refuses to load. It doesn't make any sense to me as I've got similar code throughout the page for the other input fields (to repopulate them after form submission).

As an exmaple: this works perfectly:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="lead" value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['lead'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> />Lead Required<br>
```

I've been trying to change the quote types, and tried using htmlspecialchars as well as htmlentities in the echo, but each time I leave the in statement in, it breaks the page.

As soon as I comment that if statement out, the page loads again.

Here's the input field for the $_POST['locationName'] value:

```
<input required autofocus type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9-'\s\!\@\*]+" name="locationName" maxlength="100" size="67" placeholder="Place Name" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['locationName']) ? $_POST['locationName'] : '' ?>" />
```

Comment: Any errors in the PHP error log?

Comment: @Barmar: No idea on how to view that

Comment: Well, I suggest you figure it out. You can't effectively debug scripts if you can't view the error messages.

Comment: @Daan full code is over 300 lines...

Comment: What is "breaking the page"? What exactly happens? No output? If there's no output, your `if` statement is evaluating false. If other stuff, please tell. Show us relevant code to simulate your problem.

Comment: Well this a problem we can't reproduce you need to give more information.

Comment: @AlanMachado View Source shows nothing at all. - If i remove that IF, then the page loads as it's meant to.

Comment: It's clear for me, then, that you're receiving some kind of PHP error but your error_display is disabled. Try to [enable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) it and try again.

Comment: Thanks @AlanMachado I'll give it a shot

Comment: Ok, I've managed to get some more info...
using firebug, I go to the "Net" section and it reports a "500 Internal Server Error".
What breaks _me_ is that it's that If statement that's doing it somehow.
The PHP error log not even being run because of the 500...

Comment: Are you sure that locationName is a string and not an array?

Comment: @CodrutzCodrutz i'm 99.8% certain. I'm adding the input field from the form in the post above.
(really hope the 0.2% doesn't shine through again)...

Comment: Did you enabled error display?

Comment: does `<?php echo isset($_POST['locationName']) ? $_POST['locationName'] : '' ?>` not need a semi-colon to terminate it, i.e. `<?php echo isset($_POST['locationName']) ? $_POST['locationName'] : ''; ?>`

Comment: @gabe3886 It doesn't seem to make a difference - I added the semi colon and the if statement still breaks it. while commenting the if statement out, lets the rest of the page load again.

Comment: @AlanMachado Yes I did, but because it's generating a 500 Internal Server Error somehow, nothing is being run on that page.

Comment: Is it apache? If it is, go to your apache log errors on apache root folder/logs

Comment: @AlanMachado No, I'm using Hetzner and their "KonsoleH" only errors there are 404s for robots.txt and a poorly linked favicon.ico from one of the other pages.

Comment: Oh look! "Display errors" in the "PHP config" was disabled *facepalm*
I've enabled it now and i'm getting:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ',' or ';' on line 359`
No surprises there. line 359 is:
`if (isset($_POST['locationName'])) {`

Comment: So... we have a winner(?) :D

Comment: Well, uhm, we do? I've been googling that error and still haven't found a solution to why it's breaking @AlanMachado...

Comment: Oh wow, OK, that was very blind of me. I've JUST realised what that error message meant. *feeling a little sheepish now*
I was missing the ending `;` on the previous line. I was totally distracted by the error telling me that the error was on line 359. Thanks for helping me guys!

Answer (score -2):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="lead" value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['lead'])){echo "checked='checked'";} ?> />Lead Required<br>
```

try to use braces and check

Comment: You know, if it do work just because that, it's still a problem because OP's syntax is valid as it is.

Comment: OP said that for this checkbox the syntax worked perfectly.

Comment: that error you are getting can you create fiddle link?

Comment: Thanks for trying @WisdmLabs, but no dice. (I tried it anyway - kinda desperate here)

Comment: <?php
$_POST['lead']=true;
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="lead" value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['lead'])){echo "checked='checked'";} ?> />Lead Required<br>
 put this code in phpfiddle.org

Comment: Why you no learn to markup!! — Also "try" and "check" are not valid answers!

Comment: @WisdmLabs there's a PHP fiddle?!?! - Awesome! 
When I run the block of code (the 5 checkboxes) as is, there are no errors/problems.